# Is there an official "Log in with Salesforce" image?

Tags: oauth2, authentication

Salesforce allows an external application to [authenticate using OAuth](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/intro_understanding_web_server_oauth_flow.htm). Other providers of this service offer official button images that you can embed in your application to launch this process e.g.: [image: Facebook and Google Images]

I have been unable to find the equivalent official "log in" image for Salesforce. Is there one?

Answer (score 3):

The [salesforce.com Trademark and Copyright Usage Guidelines](http://www.salesforce.com/assets/pdf/misc/salesforce_Trademark_Usage_Guidelines.pdf) seems to suggest that not only is there no official logo you may use, but using any of their logos in your app is a violation of trademark. It does outline, however, that there is a [permission form](http://www.sfdcstatic.com/assets/pdf/misc/salesforce_Permission_to_Use_Copyrighted_Work.pdf) that you can complete to enter an arrangement whereby you can use their logos in a limited fashion. I do wish they had a logo that one could use "without permission", but as far as I am aware, all salesforce.com logos are strictly for company use only. This hostile policy makes it difficult to associate your product with their platform, taking the stance that they want to protect their reputation to a much greater extent than Google, Facebook, or other online services. The [salesforce.com Trademark List](http://www.salesforce.com/assets/pdf/misc/salesforce_TM_list.pdf) outlines all current logos that you could use if you had permission to do so.

Comment: Care over misuse of their brand is fair enough. Just seems strange to offer the authentication service and then leave clients only able to show a text hyperlink which will not look great next to the carefully designed buttons of other companies.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few examples I have found :

Datafinder : http://datafinder.com/home/howitworks

http://datafinder.com/img/salesforce-logo-btn.png :

[image: Connect with Salesforce]

On this blog : http://blog.auth0.com/2013/10/18/Integrating-Heroku-Apps-with-Salesforce
http://blog.auth0.com.s3.amazonaws.com/ss-2013-10-18T11-01-43.png :

[image: Auth0 identity provider selection includes Salesforce]

On the Janrain blog : http://janrain.com/blog/how-to-set-up-salesforce-site-with-janrain-engage
http://janrain.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/SFDC-Janrain-configure-e1334859565357.png :

[image: Janrain just uses a cloud]

On the data loader.io site : https://dataloader.io/cloudhub
https://dataloader.io/sites/all/themes/dataloader_io/images/icon-login-hover.png :

[image: … so does DataLoader.io]

I hope that helps,
Rup

Comment: It does. Can you provide some links too and I'll run them by our salesforce account manager to make sure they are "official" or at least fugure out which is most "official".

Comment: I edited my answer

Comment: Perfect thanks. I'll post what I get back from our account manager.

Comment: @KeithC I'm following this-- I need to know, too. I'm making a Chrome App, and I'll be using OAuth as well.

Comment: @sfdcfox Our account manager forwarded the question internally and no response has come back. I suspect the question will go unanswered. I forwarded him a copy of what I am using - something similar to https://dataloader.io/sites/all/themes/dataloader_io/images/icon-login-hover.png that I created to match the Facebook and Google ones - so am going to assume that I have done my due diligence. Maybe one day there will be official branding for this...

Answer (score -1):

The official log of salesforce changes 3 times a year i.e. Winter, Spring and Summer.

Comment: I believe that the question is asking if there is an official "Log in with Salesforce" image and not the Logo that Salesforce has for each of its releases.